# How to get the mid values from the line graph in Tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop

Here I have datetime and the set of values. I am trying to find no.of. cycles in the line graph.

I would like to  find the mid values from the line graph as i already found min, max values using lookup function. I need some assistance in getting mid values.

| header 1 | header 2 |
| --- | --- |
| cell 1 | cell 2 |
| cell 3 | cell 4 |

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxAPp.png)

Comment: How do you define the mid values?

Comment: I need to capture the value before it rise . I can share my work book here but dont have an option here

Comment: I see that the points are located at an inflection. Is that what you mean by mid point.

Comment: Yes can you help me with sample dataset

Answer (score 0):

You can notice that all the points you are looking for are located between 12 and 16. Accordingly, filter your data with y between 12 and 16.

What you are looking for is the second derivative of the function that is above a threshold. To do that, shift your data and subtract one array from the other. That's the first derivative. Repeat the same process with the new array and get the second derivative. You can then use a threshold to pick up the points.